# How to change Windows 7 Edition from Ultimate to Ultimate N?

Tags: windows-7, conversion, windows-edition

I built a new PC and installed Windows 7 Ultimate Trial and all the necessary apps (Firefox, MSE, Skype etc..)

I then purchased a serial and tried to activate it. I got an error message saying the serial is for a different version of Windows 7 and got clarification that the serial number is for Windows 7 Ultimate N.

Does anyone know how to change my installed edition of Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 7 Ultimate N, the difference between the two editions are so small (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Sub-editions)) that I would hate to have to start all over again.

Comment: What @Diago said. On the bright side, Easy Transfer Wizard will help you back up your settings.

Comment: Since the price is the same for the N and non-N versions, contact whoever you purchased the serial number from and and exchange it for one for the version you have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot change an N edition to a Non N edition or the other way around. It requires a re-install since the SKU's are different.

The major difference is that none of the Media Player components are installed, not even at kernel level, and Microsoft actually makes a different build for the N editions.

Comment: ah ok, thanks very much for your help and responding so quickly.